# unexpected errors in verilog

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

I wrote this Verilog code on modelSim.

```
module my_fsm (clock , reset , in , out);
input   clock , reset , in;
output  out;
wire    clock , reset , in;
reg     out;    
reg [1:0] state;    // state of the machine in case reset = 0
            // A = 00 , B = 01 , C = 10 , D = don't care = 11
    always @(posedge clock) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) 
        begin
            state <= 2'b00;
            out <= 1'b0;
        end
        else 
        begin
            case (state) 
            2'b00:
                out <= 1'b0;
            if (in == 1'b1) state <= 2'b01;
            2'b01:
            out <= in;
            if (in == 1'b0) state <= 2'b10;           
            if (in == 1'b1) state <= 2'b00;           
            2'b10:
            out <= 1'b1;
            if (in == 1'b0) state <= 2'b01;           
           default:  out <= 1'bX;
           endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

But the compiler is giving me this compilation errors:

> ** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/michael/Documents/Logic Design/hw1/my_fsm .v(22): near "if": syntax error, unexpected if.
>
> ** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/michael/Documents/Logic Design/hw1/my_fsm .v(27): near "2": syntax error, unexpected INTEGER NUMBER.
>
> ** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/michael/Documents/Logic Design/hw1/my_fsm .v(30): near "default": syntax error, unexpected default.

I have looked up for those problems but couldn't find any solution for them.

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple statements in a branch of a case statement should be enclosed between `begin` and `end`. (Just like in an `if` statement, just like you've done in your `if (reset == 1'b1)` statement.)